# Building System.Data.SQLite from source with ICU enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, icu

I'm trying to build System.data.sqlite (from now on SDS) from source with ICU Tokenizer enabled. I'm using Visual studio -2010 and having trouble adding the precompiled ICU files so that SDS can compile.

I've added `#define SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU 1` to sqlite3.c, but that then gives me an error where SDS tries to include a couple of ICU header files (utypes, uregex, ustring and ucol).

Where can I include the folder containing all these files so that this will get fixed? I have never used VS more than a couple of hours in my life and I can't find a single thread that can point me in the right direction.

I've tried the c/c++ under project properties, I've tried under linker, but nothing works.

All advice appreciated.

Comment: *What* have you tried to set? The include path? To what value?

Comment: I tried including the folder containing the header files in, like I said, the properties pages for the project. I tried both under c/c++->Additional Include directories, and Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories (for the libraries that come with ICU).

Comment: And exactly where have you installed ICU? And exactly what have you entered as additional include directory?

Comment: I have not installed ICU anywhere. I got the latest ICU compiled package from their website. I have added the containing folder to the filepath. I have tried to add the containing folder as an additional include directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ICU's *include* directoy.
If you have extracted the ICU package in `C:\somewhere`, then the directory to add would be `C:\somewhere\icu\include`.

You also need to add `C:\somewhere\icu\lib` to the library path.